# How should I use the `mean` function when there are outliers in the distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, average, mean

for a project I need to get a mean each time, this mean I then use it to compare it to a distribution under the `null hypothesis H0.` However sometimes some values (**few**) are much larger than all the other values, so if I use a basic arithmetic mean these values will `greatly impact` the final mean.

Here is an example

[image]

Here if I do an arithmetic mean I get about 90, while in reality we can see that the vast majority of values on the axis are around 50.

Do you have an idea of an average that would be used in this kind of case?

Comment: Compute the `median()` in that case to remove the influence of outliers.

Comment: take this question to https://www.stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielJames I agree that this question could be answered on stats exchange, but think it's also reasonably specific to R? I interpret it as a question about functions.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Use median

`median(x)`

The median is a summary statistic which isn't 'thrown' by outliers.

### 2. Use a trimmed mean

`mean(x, trim = .05)`

A trimmed mean is the mean of all values *except* those in the highest and lowest `n`%, where `n` is a value you choose. The code above would return the mean of every value in `x` except the highest 5% and the lowest 5%.

Whatever you do, make sure you report transparently.

Comment: OK thank you but what about geometric mean? It can be appropriate as well is not it ?

Comment: @chippycentra I'm not sure. Probably a question for stats-overflow